# How is one-time-password delivery secured

Tags: passwords, sms, one-time-password

I've read about One Time Passwords on Stackoverflow, other websites, in RFC 6238 - TOTP and RFC 4226 - HOTP.

I understand OTPs are not stored in plaintext in Database, but when they are sent via SMS Gateways to the client's mobile. They have to be in plaintext.

So, can't a man in the middle, say a person at SMS Gateway, read those OTPs?

How do banks and other organizations do this securely?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GSM uses encryption in its signals. so it difficult to decode but if you know SIM CARD Details and To which BTS it latched and Hacker also in that BTS  range then it is possible to see your SMS using description logic. It required time and knowledge to decript. So TOTP are 99.9% secure.

**Lets Talk About Gateways**

1. They can be inside Banks Local/VPN Network For Security Reason.
2. Can use SSL/TLS encryption to make secure communication from banking system to GSM Gateways.

**Person at SMS GATEWAYS**

yes they can see. but if they don't have  who is the recipient or what is the text it is difficult to find, as in gateways flood of sms usually happens. Any way bank can have agreement with sms gateways for not to log OTP SMS in there system, so person at sms gateway can not see those sms.